# Only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index - but my candidate for scalar index is an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I try to implement function that will select a random picture from `tensorflow.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist`.

I stumbled upon such error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3628\3184902278.py in <module>
----> 1 show_image_labels(num_pred=16, model=model_8, data=test_data_norm, labels=test_labels, figsize=(20, 20))

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3628\1430214753.py in show_image_labels(num_pred, model, data, labels, figsize)
      6         plt.imshow(data[random_index], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
      7         pred = model.predict(data[random_index].reshape(1, 28, 28))
----> 8         plt.title(f'Prediction:{class_names[pred.argmax(axis=1)]}\nTrue label: {class_names[labels[random_index]]}\nConfidence: {np.max(pred)}')
      9         plt.axis(False)

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

This is the function:

```
def show_image_labels(num_pred=1, model=None, data=None, labels=None, figsize=(12, 12)):
    plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    for i in range(num_pred):
        ax = plt.subplot(int(num_pred/round(np.sqrt(num_pred))+2), int(num_pred/round(np.sqrt(num_pred))), i+1)
        random_index = random.choice(range(len(data)))
        plt.imshow(data[random_index], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
        pred = model.predict(data[random_index].reshape(1, 28, 28))
        plt.title(f'Prediction:{class_names[pred.argmax(axis=1)]}\nTrue label: {class_names[labels[random_index]]}\nConfidence: {np.max(pred)}')
        plt.axis(False)
```

This is the model:

```
# Set random seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)

# Create a model 
model_8 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(784, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(49, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model
model_8.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
               optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
               metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model

history_8 = model_8.fit(train_data_norm, 
                        train_labels, 
                        epochs=20,
                        batch_size=1000, 
                        validation_data=(test_data_norm, test_labels), 
                        validation_batch_size=1000)
```

And most importantly
this is the object: `array([3], dtype=int64)`

that is produced by:
`model_8.predict(test_data_norm[33].reshape(1, 28, 28)).argmax(axis=1)`.

Looks like an integer scalar array to me. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong ;>?

Comment: What about `class_names[labels[random_index]]` which is on the same line? Is `test_labels` also an integer array?

Comment: Can you display `class_names`?

Comment: Try `pred.argmax(axis=1)[0]`

Comment: @elbe 
```class_names=['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to index a list with a numpy array:

```
In [100]: alist = [1,2,3,4]; alist[np.array([1,2])]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [100], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 alist = [1,2,3,4]; alist[np.array([1,2])]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: Yes, I am :). Since it's an array that consists of integers I don't understand the problem.

Comment: A list can be indexed with one integer (or a slice).  That's python 101.